# Session in PHP seems as if it is not being created

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a user login system where you enter a username and password, you are sent to another page where those values are compared to all the users saved in a database and if a matching username and password is found it creates a session for other pages to see there is a user logged in. Here is the code:

Before the `<html>` tag and `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` tag:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "Username", "Password");

if(!$con)
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error(). "<br /> Send this text to the following mail: <a href='mailto:'support@tamankeet.com'");

mysql_select_db("tamankee_Users", $con) or die("Could not find Database: " . mysql_error() . "<br /> Send this text to the following mail: <a href='mailto:'support@tamankeet.com'>support@tamankeet.com</a>");

$User = $_POST["username"];
$Password = $_POST["password"];
$hasLoggedIn = false;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users") or die("Query error: " . mysql_error() . "<br /> Send this text to the following mail: <a href='mailto:'support@tamankeet.com'>");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $RowPass = $row['Password'];
    $RowUser = $row['Username'];
    if($Password == $RowPass && $User == $RowUser)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["UserLoggedIn"] = $User;
        $hasLoggedIn = true;
    }
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Inside `<body>` tag:

```
<?php
if($hasLoggedIn)
{
    echo "<h3 align='center'>Welcome " . $User . "!</h3>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h3 align='center'>Username / password wrong. <a href='login.php'>Try again</a></h3>";
}
?>
```

Then, in every page I have this code:

```
<?php
$Username = "";
$isUserLoggedIn = false;
if(isset($_SESSION["UserLoggedIn"]))
{
    $isUserLoggedIn = true;
    $Username = $_SESSION["UserLoggedIn"];
}
else
{
    $Username = "visitor";
    $isUserLoggedIn = false;
}

echo "Welcome " . $Username . "!";
if($isUserLoggedIn)
{
    echo " | Is this not you? <a href='http://www.tamankeet.com/Users/logout.php'>Log Out</a>";
}
else
{
    echo " | <a href='http://www.tamankeet.com/Users/login.php'>Log In</a> or <a href='http://www.tamankeet.com/Users/signup.php'>Sign Up</a>";
}
?>
```

So, I log in to an existing user, it says I logged in, I go to another page and it seems as if the session value is never set. What could be the error? (PHP version: 5.3.8)

Comment: After you logged in, check in your browser if the cookie was set successfully. Also do enable error outputting in php (`error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', true)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the use of sessions?

Basic usage:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

EDIT:

The session / cookie was being set in a subdirectory of the website, and therefore was not valid in the upper directories.
As a solution, one can try to move the code that starts the session to the main directory of the website, or, if using cookies, setting the $path parameter of the setcookie() function to "/", so the cookie will be valid across all the website.

Comment: Make sure your browser is accepting cookies and try it out with different browsers. I'd be glad to test it if you provide the URL and a valid username/password. Also, you could edit your question and add the sessions version so we can check it out.

Comment: I also tested it on firefox. Go to tamankeet.com/Users/login.php and enter:
Username:test
Password:123

Comment: You forgot to add session_start() before the statement:
if(isset($_SESSION["UserLoggedIn"]))
The $_SESSION array is available only after the call of session_start().

Comment: so you have to start session in every page before being able to check them?

Comment: That's correct. The session_start() function creates or resumes a previously created session. So, in order to resume a session, you must first call the function. It is also good practice to call session_start() at the beginning of the file, as to avoid calling the function after generating output. The session_start() function must be called before output is generated or an error will be thrown.

Comment: ok, but for some reason it still doesn't work. (Note: The session_start() is always called before the <html> and <!DOCTYPE> tags, right?)

Comment: I just tested your site and it is working for the "Home" page. Don't forget to restore the session on the other pages.
Optionally, if your code is structured in a way you have a unique point of entrance, or you have a file that's being included in all of the pages, you can take advantage of that to call session_start() one time there, instead of in every page.

Comment: on which browser, because on google chrome for some reason I can only see me being logged in under the tamankeet.com/Users dirrectory

Comment: I've just tested it again and the "Home" and "Contact Us" pages are working (the login bar at the top always says "Welcome test!"). This should

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5964/discussion-between-toms-and-rickyman20)

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be setting a cookie to time()+0.  That will set a cookie that expires immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `time() + 0`.  This makes the cookie expire now.

To make a regular cookie that will expire on browser close, only set 0 as the expr, without time added.

Comment: Still, I do that and the cookie seems to only exist only in the page where you log in. If you change page, the cookie seems to "disappear" (google chrome and firefox)

Comment: @rickyman20 - You've edited the question to correct the error and then accepted this answer :-?

Comment: It did slightly correct the answer and it still was the best answer to the problem, though you are right